# How I can delete repeated rows from database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Remove duplicates in large MySql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746616/remove-duplicates-in-large-mysql-table)
>   [Can I extract the extract records that are duplicated in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841354/can-i-extract-the-extract-records-that-are-duplicated-in-sql)
>   [How can I delete duplicate rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91784/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-rows-in-a-table)

I need something to delete repeated rows from the database.

I found out how many rows are repeated in table using this query :

```
SELECT GoodCode FROM Good_
```

and here is distinct query `SELECT Distinct GoodCode FROM Good_`

The second one has lower records. Please guide me how I can delete repeated rows from the first one.

Comment: So you want to remove the duplicates?`

Comment: yes but it should be by script I couldn't find them by my eyes there are 1 billion records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple method:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO   #TempGood
FROM   Good_

TRUNCATE TABLE Good_

INSERT Good_
SELECT *
FROM   #TempGood

DROP TABLE #TempGood
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table temptable as select distinct * from Good_;
drop table Good_;
rename temptable to Good_;
```